# Python 3 - Print Specific List Item from Dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary with lists attached to the keys with multiple values inside each list. I'm trying to pull a specific item from the lists of each key. I assumed I could do the following;

```
for entries in myDictionary:
    print("Customer :" + entries[1])
    print("Sales Rep:" + entries[2])
    print("Item: " + entries[3])
```

Though that only prints the second, third, and fourth characters of what I assume to be the key itself - it could also be the first list item as I also have the key as the first item within the lists, but I'm going to assume it's the former.

I've read about the following, but I'm unsure how to apply it to my case of wanting to print a specific item from the list. I believe these would print out the entire list per key;

```
for key, value in my_dict.iteritems():
    print key, value
for key in my_dict.iterkeys():
    print key
for value in my_dict.itervalues():
    print value
```

Cheers.

Comment: Are you using Python 2 or 3? `iter*` methods are only available in Python 2 (in Python 3 `dict` methods return iterator objects by default), but `print` is a statement, not a function, in Python 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating over the dictionary gives you *keys*; you can always use that key to access the value:

```
for key in myDictionary:
    entries = myDictionary[key]
    print("Customer:", entries[1])
    print("Sales Rep:", entries[2])
    print("Item:", entries[3])
```

Using `dict.values()` (or `dict.itervalues()` or [`dict.viewvalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.viewvalues) when using Python 2) gives you access to the values instead, which you can then index:

```
for entries in myDictionary.values():
    print("Customer:", entries[1])
    print("Sales Rep:", entries[2])
    print("Item:", entries[3])
```

or you can have both the keys and the values with `dict.items()` (`dict.iteritems()`, `dict.viewitems()`):

```
for key, entries in myDictionary.items():
    print("Details for:", key)
    print("Customer:", entries[1])
    print("Sales Rep:", entries[2])
    print("Item:", entries[3])
```